# Is it possible to hide delete icon from MultivaluedSection's rows?

Tags: ios, eureka-forms

;) hi guys!

I want delete function in `MultivaluedSection`,but I don't want display delete icon in section's rows, something like this:

```
let section2 =  MultivaluedSection(multivaluedOptions: .Delete, footer: "")
for _ in 1..<4 {
  section2 <<< PickerInlineRow<String> {
                  $0.title = "Tap to select"
                  $0.value = "client"
                  $0.options = nameList
               }
}
```

[image: demo]

I only want user swipe row to delete it.

I try solve it by check in Eureka source code,but can't find any method or property to do this.

FIX:
oh!I notice this code in Eureka demo->MultivaluedOnlyDeleteController->viewDidLoad:

```
tableView.isEditing = false
```

But,it seem not working at first time.user must tap edit button to reset editing status.

what's wrong with it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue you only have to override the `viewWillAppear` viewController method

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tableView.isEditing = false
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! you're right! Although I still don't understand why Eureka set tableView.isEditing to true in super.viewWillAppear,but thank you!

Comment: I will add further explanations about why @hopy